# Audio/Video calls doesn't work in firefox using Giggle JS

Tags: jquery, firefox, audio, video, gigglejs

If anyone has a solution for this, please share the fix.

I'm using **GiggleJS**([Website](https://github.com/valeriansaliou/giggle)) for audio/video call. The calls works on Chrome, but not on Firefox. I'm clueless as I see no errors in Browser Console.

Following is the Test Site

http://legastero.github.io/jingle-interop-demos/giggle/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with Firefox. I have found a issue filed by the Owner of GiggleJS https://github.com/valeriansaliou/giggle/issues/22